# Load file from AS to cl_gui_textedit with line breaks

Tags: textarea, binaryfiles, abap, dynpro

I want to display a file inside a `cl_gui_textedit` component with line breaks which causes me problems.

I am using the following code to initialize the component

```
  DATA: lo_c_errorviewer TYPE REF TO cl_gui_custom_container.

  CREATE OBJECT lo_c_errorviewer
    EXPORTING
        container_name = 'C_ERROR_MSG'.

  CREATE OBJECT go_error_textedit
    EXPORTING parent = lo_c_errorviewer.

  go_error_textedit->set_toolbar_mode( 0 ).
  go_error_textedit->set_statusbar_mode( 0 ).
```

After some XML processing with the iXML package the binary data of the file is available like this:

```
types: begin of xml_line,
        data(256) type x,
       end of xml_line.

data:  xml_table type table of xml_line,
       xml_size  type i.

ostream = streamFactory->create_ostream_itable( xml_table ).
document->render( ostream = ostream  recursive = 'X' ).
xml_size = ostream->get_num_written_raw( ).
```

This should contain line breaks if I am right. The ostream object has "pretty printing" turned on by default.

I searched the reference and the only way to pass the information is via

```
call method <c_textedit_control> - > set_text_as_stream
```

which expects a "Standard Table" of characters. How do I convert the data or pass it to the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier if you render your XML document into a `STRING` straight away, which you can then send to your `CL_GUI_TEXTEDIT` control:

```
data xmlstring type string.
data ostream type ref to if_ixml_ostream.
ostream = streamfactory->create_ostream_cstring( xmlstring ).
document->render( ostream = ostream recursive = 'X' ).
...
data textedit type ref to cl_gui_textedit.
create object textedit
  exporting
    parent = container.
textedit->set_textstream( xmlstring ).
```

If you must render into binary data, then I suggest you use an `XSTRING` for that:

```
data xmlxstring type xstring.
data ostream type ref to if_ixml_ostream.
ostream = streamfactory->create_ostream_xstring( xmlxstring ).
document->render( ostream = ostream recursive = 'X' ).
```

You can then convert the binary data to a string, using the `CL_ABAP_CONV_IN_CE` class provided by SAP:

```
data converter type ref to cl_abap_conv_in_ce.
converter = cl_abap_conv_in_ce=>create( input = xmlxstring ).
data xmlstring type string.
converter->read( importing data = xmlstring ).
```

Which you can send to your `CL_GUI_TEXTEDIT` control:

```
data textedit type ref to cl_gui_textedit.
create object textedit
  exporting
    parent = container.
textedit->set_textstream( xmlstring ).
```

Note that in case you run into encoding issues, you can set the encoding on the ostream object before rendering, and the converter object allows you to specify encoding when you create it.